# How to reduce file size of g++ compiled shared object?

Tags: optimization, g++, shared-objects

I have a shared object (.so) file compiled with g++, in Windows, its size about 2MB (.DLL, compiled with Visual Studio 2008, /O2), but in Linux, its size is 10MB if compiled with g++ -O2 flag.

Even I compile it with -Os flag, the final .so file size still have 5MB.

I know the executable can be reduced by strip command, but it seems not working with .so file (it can be stripped, but unable to load).

How can I reduce file size of this shared object? Are there any strip command for shared object?

**Edit1:**

My g++ version is 4.1.2. I use Boost 1.43 in my code.

The compile flags in my makefile:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -D_PYTHON -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -I"boost_1_43_0" -I"/usr/local/include/python2.6" -fno-tree-vrp -Os -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o"$@" "$<"
```

The link flags:

```
LIBS := -lm -lz -ltidy -lpng14 -lxml2 -liconv -lboost_regex-gcc41-mt-s -lboost_serialization-gcc41-mt-s -lboost_python-gcc41-mt-s -lpython2.6
```

Here is ldd for my shared object:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00327000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x004f4000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00110000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00f31000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0053b000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00328000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0077d000)
```

I will try with -fno-inline flag, but I was wondering this would impact performance of compiled code.

I doubt that is because I link statically against python 2.6? There should be libpython2.6.so in my ldd, but I don't see it.

Are there something wrong in my link or compile flags?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake, I tried -Os, this results 5MB, my original post said 5MB is compiled with -O1, that's wrong. I fixed the post.

Comment: That's all I got then, sorry.

Comment: Please post `ldd $target.so` and try -fno-inline etc. Are you using any special template features (MSVC++ extern templates e.g.?)

Comment: I don't use any special template features, all the syntax I used are follow the standard. If there are any fancy features I used, it might be Boost library, like Boost::MPL, Boost::Tuple, Boost::Variant etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those external libraries are static, they are being incorporated into your library. I suspect this because ldd is not showing a link to them and this is a frequent cause of huge executables.

The -static linker option in g++ can cause this problem, or maybe the libraries you are linking are only available as static libraries.